# Checking the return value of a C program in a bash script?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I have a bash script in which i check the exit code of a last run command by using $? variable but now I am executing a C program (from that script) which returns 0 if the program gets executed successfully. Is there any way I can catch this return value of the C program from with in my bash script?

I believe different commands like awk, sed etc are written in C. How do they use $? to store their exit codes in it? How can I make my C program to store its exit code in $??

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no need to do anything - if your C program returns 0, that's what will be stored in the `$?` variable of the shell that executed it.

Comment: The exit status is limited to only 8 bits, so only the lowest 8 bits of what the program returns will end up stored in $?

Comment: @Chris Dodd - POSIX limits the return value to be from 0 - 255 anyway, so 8 bit storage isn't a problem there, it's an optimization.

Answer (score 2):

The return code of a C program is the value returned by `int main()` function or the argument of `exit()` function. The system then makes it available to its parent process through the `wait()` system call. When the parent process is `bash`, this value is then made available through the `$?` variable.

Comment: What makes you think errno is involved?

Comment: I make the assumption that a new process is created with `fork()` and its man page mentions that. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, Windows (on which I use bash) doesn't have fork(). And in over 25 years of UNIX programming, I've never seen any suggestion that errno is associated with a process's exit value. I'm not saying you are wrong, but I'd need chapter & verse before saying you are right.

Comment: After further research, I found that I am wrong. The exit code of the child process is retrieved by its parent process via the wait() system call. I speak of Unix, I don't know Windows. I edit my answer. Thank you for your intervention.

Answer (score 1):

bash catches the exit code in `$?` automagically. Or you can just use the command in `if` if you only care about zero/non-zero.